# How can I fix a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have 2 tables, products and images. What I want to do is select all the products from the product table where condition (a column of product table) is "used" and inner join images using product-name (column of products and images table -foreign key).

I have tried using select all, inner joint and where clause.

```
(
"SELECT * FROM  `products` p " 
   where condition="used"

 + "INNER JOIN  `images` i "
 + "USING (  `product-name` ) "
         
)
```

Comment: What is that???  What's with the bracket, double quote, the black thing before INNER JOIN and USING.  How do you expect it to work?  Have you even check MySQL documentation how to create a query?

Comment: Well said @Eric. Also `product-name` is `product` minus `name`. Welcome to SO @s.am.i. Precise questions get much better responses, don't be put off, keep asking but improve the clarity.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes...brackets are because of i am using it inside if statement..and that black thing was + i typed it as + but it appeared as black thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get a syntax error, consult the [manual on SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). `WHERE` clauses come after `JOIN` like:

```
SELECT * FROM products p
INNER JOIN images i USING ( `product-name` )
WHERE condition="used"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the inner join links the two tables "products" and "images". In the ON clause the condition "products.product-name = images.product-name" defines how the two tables should be joined with each other(on product-name).

```
SELECT * FROM products
INNER JOIN images
ON products.product-name = images.product-name
WHERE condition = 'used'
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some commentary to explain your code. Do not expect everyone to understand what you have posted. Explanations are key.